# Update Query With If In Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How we can write a if condition in Laravel Update Query

My Query Is

```
UPDATE users SET user_counter = IF(user_counter=0,0,user_counter-1), user_live_counter = IF(user_live_counter=0,0,user_live_counter-1) WHERE user_id = 2(some id)
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Laravel 5.2 but 5.3 is in your question title? Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options. If you want to use Eloquent, first get the user:

```
$user = User::find(2);
```

or, if `id` isn't the name of your id column:

```
$user = User::where('user_id', 2)->first();
```

then update:

```
$user->user_counter = $user->user_counter == 0 ? 0 : 1;
$user->user_live_counter = $user->user_live_counter == 0 ? 0 : 1;
$user->save();
```

or even this will work (though it probably doesn't look as clean in my opinion):

```
$user->update([
    'user_counter' => $user->user_counter == 0 ? 0 : 1,
    'user_live_counter' => $user->user_live_counter == 0 ? 0 : 1,
]);
```

Another interesting way could be by using [Eloquent's Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator).

You can also simply write a raw query using the DB facade:

```
$updatedUser = DB::statement("
    UPDATE 
        users
    SET 
       user_counter = CASE WHEN user_counter = 0 THEN 0 ELSE user_counter + 1 END,
       user_live_counter = CASE WHEN user_live_counter = 0 THEN 0 ELSE user_live_counter + 1 END
    WHERE
        user_id = 2;
");
```

Answer (score -1):

Just to add to the answer of @tptcat. Just remember that if you use the raw query using the Laravel's query builder, it is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: How is it vulnerable to SQL injection when the query is not using user input? I wish people would quit constantly warning about SQL injection in every question about the DB